# Does the 6 months validity of non-EU driver's license for new residents of Germany affect their ability to drive in other EU countries?

Tags: germany, eu, driving-license

It is well known that new residents in Germany can only use their non-EU drivers license up to 6 months after relocating there. Other EU countries have similar rules, such as Italy - although there the period is 1 year.

Based on that, I've seen people staying that, if you take residence in Germany and do not get a local driver's license after the 6 months period, you cannot use your valid, non-EU driver's license in other EU countries.

For example, if I were to visit Italy after living in Germany for 2 years, I wouldn't be allowed to drive there with my non-EU license, even if the license is valid and fulfills all of the criteria required from non-EU resident tourists.

As far as I understand, driving regulations in the EU are defined locally by each member state and I have never been able to find a single country's regulation stating that the local rules of place of residence of the driver somehow affect their own rules. Is that really a thing?

Comment: Not only in Germany. Most jurisdiction require that you have a drivers license issued in the area you are a resident of (US/Canada the state or provence) and must be replaced when moving. The EU is an exception that the license need not be replaced while it is still valid. But when being replaced or renewed that must be done in the country of residence.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's already mentioned in the last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: @Relaxed The point is that most police officials checking a drivers lincense will wonder why the license is not from the same jurisdiction that the person resides in. So yes, it is 'a thing'.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Uh? What is that based on? In any case, if that's what you meant, it would be an answer and a point you entirely failed to make in your earlier comment, which did not add anything to what's already in the question. If you really believe that, I suggest posting it an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

When you take residence in Germany, then your ID gets associated with Germany; so as long as they have your driver's license registered, then its expiration date gets internally updated to be within 6 months of the move date.  So you are correct, if you go to Italy 2 years later, your driver's license would be internally expired by then, and you would not be allowed to drive.

There are some workarounds to this, however.  If you get registered in Italy for a day before the 6-month period is up, and then back in Germany, then the 6-month period starts over, and in this manner you can continue to extend your driver's license until its true expiration date.

The other thing I've done is, not tell them that I have a valid driver's license.  Obviously, I would not drive in the EU, or carry it without an RF shield (several unrelated people told me their driver's licenses got automatically registered after being detected by RF waves from a Polizei car).  Theoretically, if you ever need to drive, you can do the registration country change back and forth; and if you get stopped, they would see that your registration in Germany is recent, and you would avoid trouble.  However, I myself haven't done this, since driving even once in EU would risk that the driver's license would get associated with your identity, and at that point you'd have to keep doing the back-and-forth registration to keep your license from expiring.